# Add a new column to SELECT if elements of an INNER JOIN exists

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have 3 table PERSONS, COMPANIES and PERSON_CUSTOMER_COMPANY which makes the relation n-to-n if the person is a customer of the company (a person may be others relations with each company).

This query returns all companies that have a relation with a given person as a Customer (line 3 inner join).

```
select co.name from COMPANIES co  
            INNER JOIN PERSONS p on p.COMPANY_ID = co.id 
            INNER JOIN PERSON_CUSTOMER_COMPANY pcc on pcc.PERSON_ID = p.PERSON_ID 
            WHERE p.PERSON_ID = 123456;
```

I need to change this query to return all companies from a person even if they are not related in the PERSON_CUSTOMER_COMPANY and an extra field indicating if the person is a customer of the company.

Something like "isCustomer"

```
select co.name, isCustomer from COMPANIES co ...
```

Comment: I don't get your data model.  All three tables don't seem necessary for this.  How is person connected to company?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don´t understand it in full either. It is a legacy system and I had to obscure some details.

Answer (score 1):

An `inner join` will only return results that match in both tables.  Since you are looking for potential companies that don't have records in the `person_customer_company` table, then you need an `outer join` instead.  Then you can use a `case` statement to create the new column:

```
SELECT co.name, 
    CASE WHEN pcc.Person_id IS NULL then 'No' else 'Yes' End as IsCustomer 
FROM COMPANIES co  
    INNER JOIN PERSONS p on p.COMPANY_ID = co.id 
    LEFT JOIN PERSON_CUSTOMER_COMPANY pcc on pcc.PERSON_ID = p.PERSON_ID 
WHERE p.PERSON_ID = 123456;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use `exists`:

```
SELECT co.name, 
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM PERSON p
                          WHERE p.COMPANY_ID = co.id  AND
                                p.PERSON_ID = 123456
                         )
             THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No'
        END) as IsCustomer
FROM COMPANIES co;
```

This only uses `PERSON`, because that is the `JOIN` you use in your query.

I suspect you really want:

```
SELECT co.name, 
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM PERSON_CUSTOMER_COMPANY pcc
                          WHERE pcc.COMPANY_ID = co.id  AND
                                pcc.PERSON_ID = 123456
                         )
             THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No'
        END) as IsCustomer
FROM COMPANIES co;
```

In either case, only two table are necessary.

Comment: This returns all companies, not just those where the person has a relationship...  OP states `return all companies from a person` - I think this is why the `join` is needed.